# Moving inside identifier-words (underscore, camelcase) in vim

Tags: vim

I would like a quick way to move between parts of a word e.g.:

```
this_is_a_variable_name
^    ^  ^ ^        ^

thisIsAFunctionName
^   ^ ^^       ^
```

---

This would increase the speed in certain situations when only part of the word needs to be modified / deleted e.g.:

```
+--------+----------------------+------------------+---------------------+
| change | k_error_write_stream | sendAckMessage   | printMessageAndExit |
| to     | k_error_read_stream  | sendReplyMessage | printMessage        |
+--------+----------------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

`camelcasemotion` (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) is a vim plugin that adds this feature. It sets up mappings for `,w` `,b` `,e` behaving like Vi's own `w` `b` `e` but for both CamelCase and underscore_naming.

Comment: If you don't like the key bindings, you can always download the plugin, see how the mechanics work and set your own mappings.

Comment: If you don't like the key bindings... read the configuration section of the plugin.